# How to alternatively wait on a dynamic set of Ballerina future values?

Tags: async-await, concurrency, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a requirement of writing a ballerina util function that can alternatively wait on a given set of futures and return the result, where the number of future values can vary as shown in the below **pseudo** source code.

```php
function getWaitResult(future[] futures) returns any|error {
    return wait futures[0] | futures[1] | ... | futures[n];
}
```

What would be the best approach to have the same functionality implemented using Ballerina Swan Lake versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to provide each future reference statically, I would suggest you to generate more strands combining alternate wait actions.

```php
import ballerina/lang.runtime;
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/random;

function waitHelper(future<any>[] fs) returns any|error {
    match fs {
        var [f] => {
            return wait f;
        }
        var [f, x] => {
            return wait f | x;
        }
        var [f, x, y] => {
            return wait f | x | y;
        }
        var [f, x, y, ...r] => {
            var rest = start waitHelper(r);
            return wait f | x | y | rest;
        }
    }
}

function foo() returns int {
    int r = checkpanic random:createIntInRange(10, 200);
    io:println("waiting (ms)... ", r);
    runtime:sleep((<decimal>r)/1000);
    return r;
}

public function main() {
    future<int>[] f = [];
    foreach int i in 0...9 {
        var r = start foo();
        f.push(r);
    }
    any|error got = waitHelper(f);
    io:println("Got: ", got);
}
```